# How do you run a child class' overriden method when using generics in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
   public abstract class BaseObject { 
        //even though this does not have abstract methods I declare it as abstract because I do not want it to be initialized
        ....
        public void save(Connection con) {
           con.InsertOrReplace(this);
        }
        ....
   }

   public abstract CheckedDataObject : BaseDataObject {
        ....
        public abstract new void save(Connection con);
   }
```

These two classes are used by my data objects, some of them simply need to be saved, others have to run checks before being saved, and since the checks are different the save method in CheckedDataObject is abstract

for example:

```
public class Father : BaseDataObject {

}
```

this just needs to be saved , BaseDataObject's save works correctly but:

```
public class Child : CheckedDataObject {
     ....
     public override void save(Connection con) {
        //do checks here to see if it is correct, if not throw an exception
        con.Insert(this);
     }
     ....


}
```

My problem is when I use a generic method to save a list of objects (some may be father, some may be children) like this:

```
public void save_all<T>(Connection con, List<T> items) where T: BaseDataObject {
    foreach (int idx = items.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //initializations and checks go here
        items[i].save(con);
    }
}
```

The problem is that save()  always calls BaseDataObject's save even when the item being parsed is a CheckedDataObject

How can I alter my method so that it will call the correct save method?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Where is `BaseDataObject` ?  Or is `BaseObject`  misspelled? Fix that.

Comment: Nice example of violation of [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Why don't you just make save virtual in the base class allowing people to override it? The title of your question suggests maybe this is what you meant to do - you talk as if you have overriden the method rather than creating an entirely new one which is actually what you seem to have done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/whats-the-difference-between-override-and-new/

I guess that your problem comes from the point that you're using `new` in `CheckedDataObject.Save`, so when you iterate and your condition is `where T: BaseDataObject`, the called method will be always BaseObject.save or it's overrides.

Try to use `override` instead `new` in `CheckedDataObject`

Comment: yeah replacing new with override seems to work on my test project, much cleaner than the solution I found, thanks a lot

Comment: @Juan this is their 44th question, I think they know how that works.

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess you mean "his" and "he", not "their" and "they". Anyways, said it cause he found it valid and mb he forgot to do it. Regards!

Comment: @Juan no, I did not mean to assume their gender. Why do you say that?

Comment: @CodeCaster Cause their/they is for plural, so I didnt know who you were referring to...

Comment: yeah I accepted it , sorry for being late, it wouldn't let me do it too early.

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow thanks, had no idea of that :O. New thing learnt from asnwering a question ^^, thanks again (still, it sounds very strange for me to use they as singular :S)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is simply one base class with a virtual method like this:

```
  public abstract class BaseObject
  {
     public virtual void Save(Connection con)
     {
         con.InsertOrReplace(this);
     }
  }

  public class Father : BaseObject
  {
      public override void Save()
      {
       // no checks needed?
       base.Save();
      }
  }

  public class Child : BaseObject
  {
    public override void Save()
    {
     //do checks here to see if it is correct, if not throw an exception
     base.Save();
    }
  }
```

What is the use of `CheckedDataObject`? I dont see it.

If you have a Collections of `BaseObject` now and call the `Save` method, the overridden method of the derived class will be called.

Comment: no that wouldn't work, both BaseDataObject and CheckedDataObject have properties and methods belonging to them , I just wrote dots in their place, I thought that would mean "there's other stuff here too" , sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, don't use `new`, use `override`, and declare the function in the base class `virtual`.

```
  public abstract class BaseObject { 
        //even though this does not have abstract methods I declare it as abstract because I do not want it to be initialized
        ....
        public virtual void save(Connection con) {
           con.InsertOrReplace(this);
        }
        ....    }

   public abstract CheckedDataObject : BaseDataObject {
        ....
        public override void save(Connection con);    }
```

Second, perhaps you should use interfaces instead of abstract classes?

Third, is `BaseObject` som kind of model? If so, perhaps you shold put saving in an other (e.g. repository) class. ([Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Comment: nah I just ommited a lot of code that BaseDataObject has that should be there, properties and methods, that's why I went with abstract classes, thanks for the reply

Answer (score -1):

So, there is a simple solution: cast to CheckedDataObject. But if I were you I would prefer to avoid using this class hierarchy  .

```
public void save_all<T>(Connection con, List<T> items) where T: BaseDataObject {
foreach (int idx = items.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    //initializations and checks go here
    var cdo = items[i] as CheckedDataObject;
    if (cdo != null)
        cdo.save(con);
    else
        items[i].save(con);
}}
```

Comment: that was similar to the the way I did it, ** if (item[i] is CheckedDataObject) { ((CheckedDataObject)(object)items[i]).save(con); } else { items[i].save(con); }  **  I was just looking for a better way, sorry for not mentioning that earlier